# Excel: FREQUENCY function, why this result [PICTURES]

Tags: excel, statistics, histogram, frequency

So I have this 15 data rows and 4 bins and I calculate `FREQUENCY` for each bin, starting from one row before the first bin and ending with the last bin:

[image]

What I don't understand is what this result mean. The first bin is `6 036 615 492,14` which I take means the interval of `minus infinity` to `6 036 615 492,14`. The `FREQUENCY` function says that there's `1` data inside that interval. However, then I try to calculate frequency starting from `6 036 615 492,14` and going one row after the last bin:

[image]

The results changed:[image]

Why?? I'm also confused what blue `1` after `15 818 778 835,82` bin means. `15 818 778 835,82` is the maximum number in that data column, so there can't possibly be any number in the interval from `15 818 778 835,82` to  `plus infinity`.

At the same time there's an orange `1` before `6 036 615 492,14`, while that is the minimum number in the data column already.

**EDIT**: Tried it again, checked the formula - see the screen.

[image]

Comment: You say you are using the `FREQUENCY` function, but what are the precise formulas you are using?? Please edit question to include this information.

Comment: If you are using the same FREQUENCY formula, array entered in 5 cells then it doesn’t matter which 5 cells you use, the result will still be the same

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 The formulas are the same in all cells: the array of data, the array of intervals, all completely the same.

Comment: @barry houdini But it looks like it does. See edit, I double checked it and added more scheenshots.

Comment: @Ans I don't know what it causing this exactly, but I think the problem should be fixed if you enter it as an array formula (press Ctrl+Shift+Enter after typing rather than just Enter).

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 It's already at array formula - you can see `{` and `}` on screens. My only guess is it happens because it still calculates the same data for the same input and just outputs it into the cells I showed it and since in the second case I showed another cells as an output source so it outputed the same result just in differen cells.